# Why aren't move parameters staying with my object?

Tags: modeling

I'm really new to Blender, and just having difficulty understanding the 3D cursor.

I don't know what I did but for some reason my movement controls will not stay with the object I am editing. I don't get why this is happening, and I can't seem to get them to stay with the object.  I've tried resetting the 3D cursor, setting a new origin point, using Shift + S and selecting the object, but when I go to move, rotate, scale my object the control parameters just won't follow the object as they were before.

[image]

In the image you'll see what I'm talking about.  How can I get my controls to follow the object again?

Thanks,
 A Blender Noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option menu two boxes to the right of where it says Object Mode, is the Pivot Point, you have it set to 3D Cursor. Change it to Median. I think that is what you are asking, but you may need to be more clear. :)

Comment: Ah yes that worked!  Thank you!  I know it was a little hard to understand my question, but I wasn't really sure how else to state it.